# Create a temporary keras session?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a bunch of models floating around, I clone them, cross-validate them, do hyperparameter selection and what have you.  As such, my `keras` global session can get quite mucked up.  The solution per [various threads](http://forums.fast.ai/t/how-could-i-release-gpu-memory-of-keras/2023/11) is to call `.clear_session()`.  However, this will throw away any models that I want to *keep*.  One option is to train all of my models in a `multiprocessing` thread.  However, it would be convenient to just instantiate a new session for each model as one might do with Tensorflow:

```
def score_model(**hyperparameters):
    with tf.Graph().as_default() 
        my_model = build_model(**hyperparameters)
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            my_model.train(X,y)
            score = my_model.score()
    # now it's all gone, I have the score, so I don't need the model anymore
    # the rest of my_model should get garbage collected, hooray!
    return score
```

Can I do this sort of thing with `keras`?

**UPDATE**

The `sess.as_default()` method is crashing my kernel.  My memory does not seem to be running low, and it gives no error whatsoever.  In the following loop I can't even make it to `i=2` before crashing.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import numpy as np
import sklearn
import keras
import keras.wrappers.scikit_learn
import tensorflow as tf
import keras.models
import os


def sessioned(f):
    def sessioned_f(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not hasattr(self, "sess"):
            self.sess = tf.Session()
        with self.sess.as_default():
            return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return result
    return sessioned_f

class LogisticRegression(keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier):   
    def __init__(self, n_epochs=100, **kwargs):
        self.n_epochs = n_epochs
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
    @sessioned
    def fit(self, X, y,**kwargs):
        # get the shape of X and one hot y
        self.input_shape = X.shape[-1]
        self.label_encoder = sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
        self.label_encoder.fit(y)
        self.output_shape = len(self.label_encoder.classes_)
        label_encoded = self.label_encoder.transform(y).reshape((-1,1))
        y_onehot = sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder().fit_transform(label_encoded).toarray()
        super().fit(X,y_onehot,epochs=self.n_epochs,verbose=1,**kwargs)
        return self
    @sessioned
    def predict_proba(self, X):
        return super().predict_proba(X)
    def check_params(self, params):
        #fuckit
        pass
    @sessioned
    def __call__(self): # the build_fn thing
        # create model
        model = keras.models.Sequential()
        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(self.output_shape, input_dim=self.input_shape, kernel_initializer="normal", activation="softmax"))
        # Compile model
        model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
        return model

data = load_iris()
i=0
while True:
    print(i)
    graph = tf.Graph()
    with graph.as_default():
        model = LogisticRegression()
        model.fit(data.data, data.target)
        model.sess.close()
        del model
    i+=1
    del graph
```

Comment: What do you mean "this will throw away any models"? The session just runs the computation graph, your model stays as is.

Comment: [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Session#close) suggests that the resources allocated for the purpose of training my model will be released when the `with` block ends.  Including, hopefully, weight tensors and such.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Keras exactly as you described, except instead of running Tensorflow code inside the with statements you run the Keras code.

To set the session you would use

```
with sess.as_default()
```

Here is a link with with more information:
https://blog.keras.io/keras-as-a-simplified-interface-to-tensorflow-tutorial.html

I have also found it helpful to look at the source code inside keras.backend. If you look at get_session() you can see that Keras first looks to see if there is a tensorflow default session. Otherwise it uses the session set to Keras using set_session(). Finally if no session has been set then it creates one.

Comment: I took a look at the `clear_session` and `set_session` code.  Bizarrely, `clear_session` seems to only reset the graph, and does not close the old session.  I suppose that they are hoping garbage collection will come clean it up?

Comment: Do I also need to `K.set_session(sess)` per the linked tutorial before `sess.as_default()`?  The plan is to create a new session for each model..

Comment: Indeed, the tutorial you link to only ever uses the global keras `SESSION_`, since it sets the `keras` session to be the same `sess` that they use for everything at the very beginning of the script.  How does `SESSION_` behave when I create multiple sessions?

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean in the blog post. However I just checked it and you do not need to use set_session()

Comment: This does not work.  Please see my update on the matter.